# Como llenar una matriz con números aleatorios entre 8 y 32

Tags: java

tengo una pregunta

¿Cómo para generar un matriz bidimensional con números aleatorios entre 8 y 32 ?. tengo el siguiente método llamado llenar, pero solo esta generando números aleatorios entre 0 y 32.

```
public int[][] llenar() {

       int[][] matriz = new int[12][4];
       for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
               matriz[i][j] = (int) (Math.random()  * 32);
           }
       }
       return matriz;
   }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no conozco algún método específicamente entre 2 números pero podrías intentar con lo siguiente:

```
Random r = new Random();
int inicio = 8;
int fin = 32;
int resultado = r.nextInt(fin-inicio) + inicio;
```

Answer (score 0):

debes obtener el numero aleatorio comprendido entre 8 y 32 de esta forma:

```
int aleatorio = (int) ((Math.random() * (33 - 8)) + 8);
```

este serìa el còdigo, para que tu matrìz se llene con estos numeros:

```
       int[][] matriz = new int[12][4];
       for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
               matriz[i][j] = (int) ((Math.random() * (33 - 8)) + 8);
           }
       }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo

Comment: @AndresR Recuerda marcar como soluciòn la respuesta que haya resuelto el problema planteado en la pregunta, revisa [tour], saludos.